# Get Running Sum From Many Object's Most Recent Record (Javascript & D3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, javascript-objects, rollup

**(Note: Updated partial answer at bottom)**

I am hoping to create a D3 line chart with a running sum of many objects whose values can change over time.

The data is structured like this...

```
  const data = [
    {"id": 1, "object": "A", "date": "2019-10-01", "value": 324},
    {"id": 2, "object": "A", "date": "2019-10-06", "value": 123},
    {"id": 3, "object": "A", "date": "2019-10-12", "value": 37},
    {"id": 4, "object": "B", "date": "2019-09-24", "value": 16},
    {"id": 5, "object": "B", "date": "2019-10-16", "value": 17},
    {"id": 6, "object": "B", "date": "2019-10-24", "value": 14},
    {"id": 7, "object": "B", "date": "2019-10-25", "value": 44},
    {"id": 8, "object": "C", "date": "2019-10-02", "value": 62},
    {"id": 9, "object": "C", "date": "2019-10-06", "value": 74},
    {"id": 10, "object": "C", "date": "2019-10-16", "value": 64},
  ];
```

For a certain date, say 2019-10-12, I am having trouble aggregating the changes on this date (ID 3), with the most recent values from the other Objects. For example, the data point at 2019-10-12 should be the sum of values for ID 3, ID 4, and ID 9.

The below code only shows grouped values on that day, not including the aggregate most recent values from other objects. For example, for 2019-10-16, it will sum ID 5 and ID 10, but doesn't also include ID 3 (which it should).

```
  const svg = DOM.svg(500 , 500);
  const parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
  data.forEach(d => {d.date = parse(d.date)});

  const groupedData = d3.rollups(data, v => d3.sum(v, d => d.value), d => d.date)
  
  const dateMinMax = d3.extent(groupedData, d => d[0]) // d[0] is date
  const xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain(dateMinMax).range([0, 500])
  const valueMinMax = d3.extent(groupedData, d => d[1]) // d[1] is value
  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(valueMinMax).range([0, 500])
  d3.select(svg).selectAll('circle').data(groupedData).enter()
      .append('circle')
        .attr('fill', 'green')
        .attr('cy', d => yScale(d[1]))
        .attr('cx', d => xScale(d[0]))
        .attr("r", 5);

  return svg
```

**--------What I have tried...--------**

I have made a array of all the unique dates, and then used that to create an array of objects, with curr_date and a Map of all the changes that happened on that day. I began working on the commented out line, my idea was to create a loop that would look at previous dates from most recent to oldest and append IDs to the curr_date "changes" mapping for objects that do not yet exist in the mapping, but I felt like I was going down the wrong path, because looping over all previous dates does not seem efficient.

```
  const parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
  rawData.forEach(d => {
    d.date = parse(d.date)
  });

  const sortedData = rawData.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.date, b.date));
  
  const allActiveDates = sortedData.map(d => d.date.getTime())
  const allActiveDatesNoDuplicates = [...new Set(allActiveDates)].map(d => new Date(d)) // remove duplicates.

  const sortedDataLookup = d3.index(sortedData, d => d.date, d => d.id)

  const changes =  allActiveDatesNoDuplicates.map((curr_date, index, array) => {
    
    //return array.slice(0,index).reverse().forEach()
    
    return {curr_date, changes: sortedDataLookup.get(curr_date)}
  });

  return changes
```

An alternative idea I had was to do a `LEAD(date) OVER (Partition by Object)`, so I now have a startdate and an enddate for each row. Then I could do... (pseudocode following)... `cumsum(value) by startdate - cumsum(value) by enddate`. But don't feel like the overhead of adding SQL to this is the right way to go either.

Any ideas? Thank you!

**-------------------UPDATE-------------------**

The below code works. It returns an array of objects. Each object has a date, and an array of all the most recent object records up to that day. So I do not think this will be hard to turn into the d3 visual I am looking for.

**However**, I feel like this solution will not scale well and am still hoping for guidance. I don't think it will scale well because *availableRecords* will get pretty large, and every mapping having more mappings within it seems like a lot of loops. I feel like it's a relatively simple problem that I am overcomplicating.

```
{
  
  const rawData = [
    {"id": 1, "object": "A", "date": "2019-10-01", "value": 324},
    {"id": 2, "object": "A", "date": "2019-10-06", "value": 123},
    {"id": 3, "object": "A", "date": "2019-10-12", "value": 37},
    {"id": 4, "object": "B", "date": "2019-09-24", "value": 16},
    {"id": 5, "object": "B", "date": "2019-10-16", "value": 17},
    {"id": 6, "object": "B", "date": "2019-10-24", "value": 14},
    {"id": 7, "object": "B", "date": "2019-10-25", "value": 44},
    {"id": 8, "object": "C", "date": "2019-10-02", "value": 62},
    {"id": 9, "object": "C", "date": "2019-10-06", "value": 74},
    {"id": 10, "object": "C", "date": "2019-10-16", "value": 64},
  ];

  const parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
  rawData.forEach(d => {
    d.date = parse(d.date)
  });

  const sortedData = rawData.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.date, b.date));

  const days = d3.groups(sortedData, d => d.date) // 2D Array (date array[object array])
  
  const changes = days.map((day, index, all_days) => {
    
    const availableRecords = all_days.slice(0,index+1)//.reverse()
    const availableRecordsFlat = availableRecords.map(d => d[1]).flat(1)

    const availableObjects = [...new Set(availableRecordsFlat.map(d => d.object))]
    const availableObjectsRecentRecord = availableObjects.map(d => {
      const records = availableRecordsFlat.filter(r => r.object == d).sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a.date, b.date));
      const recentRecord = records[0]
      
      return {d, recentRecord}
    });
    
    const date = day[0]
    return {date: date, currentRecords: availableObjectsRecentRecord}
  });

  return changes
}
```